# Подсчет уникальных букв в слове

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Пользователь вводит слово, подсчитайте количество уникальных букв в этом слове.

Повторяющиеся считаем за одну, в слове "окно" - три уникальные буквы, "о", "к", "н".

Используйте только final-переменные. Подсказка: используйте массив.

Какую-то часть сделал, сохраняю в массив количество, ввожу `окно`, выводится `1 1 1`, а надо что бы выводилось `3`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Введите слово: ");

final String str = sc.next();

final char[] ch = str.toCharArray();

final int[] count = new int[str.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {

  if (i != str.indexOf(ch[i])) {
    count[i] = -1;
  }

  if (count[i] != -1) {
    count[i]++;
    final int[] count1 = new int[count[i]];
    final int sum = count1.length;
    System.out.print(sum + " ");
  }

}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));

for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  if (count[i] == 1) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Посмотри внимательно в коде что хранится в переменной, которую ты выводишь.

Answer (score 0):

Если задача в том, чтобы посчитать только *количество уникальных **букв***, это можно сделать безо всяких `final` массивов при помощи Stream API:

```java
public static int countUniqueLetters(String str) {
    return (int) str.chars()         // IntStream стрим кодовых точек строки
        .filter(Character::isLetter) // оставить только буквы
        .distinct()                  // оставить уникальные буквы
        .count();                    // подсчитать количество
}
```

Аналогичное решение с использованием `Set`, хранящего только уникальные элементы, и *только `final` переменных*:

```java
public static int countUniqueLettersSet(String str) {
    final Set<Character> uniqueLetters = new HashSet<>();
    for (final char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            uniqueLetters.add(c);
        }
    }
    return uniqueLetters.size();
}
```

---

Само по себе требование *использовать только `final` переменные* несколько странное, так как `final` переменной значение может присваиваться только один раз, таким образом переменная-счётчик для подсчёта букв НЕ может быть финальной (её значение должно меняться).
Объявление же массива `final` не запрещает изменять значения внутри этого массива.

Вариант решения может заключаться в том, чтобы пройтись по массиву символов начальной строки и "пометить" все дубликаты (например, сбросив их в 0-й символ), увеличивая счетчик только для первого вхождения:

```java
public static int countUniqueLettersArray(final String str) {
    final char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    final int[] count = {0}; 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(arr[i])) {
            continue;  // пропускаем не-буквы (в т.ч. нулевые символы)
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {  // найден дубликат
                arr[j] = '\0';       // устанавливаем нулевой символ
            }
        }
        count[0]++;
    }
    return count[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с сортировкой массива. Упрощает подсчет уникальных символов, увеличивая счетчик только при отличии текущего символа от предыдущего в отсортированном массиве. Все переменные (вообще все :)) - final.

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите слово: ");
        final String str = sc.next();
        final char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(ch);

        final char[] buf = {0};
        final int[] counter = {0};
        for (final char c : ch) {
            if (buf[0] != c) {
                buf[0] = c;
                counter[0]++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter[0]);
    }
}
```

```
Введите слово: абвгдабвгд
5
```

Comment: сложность простого побуквенного подсчета - O(n). Сложность с сортировкой O(n log n) в общем случае, а в худшем случае О(n^2).

Comment: @Эникейщик точно *сложность простого побуквенного подсчета - O(n)*? - ведь придётся сверять очередную букву с массивом уникальных букв, здесь близко к O(n^2), если я правильно понимаю

Comment: зачем массив. Нужно хэшсет или хэшмэп, а там сложность проверки O(1) почти всегда. И даже в массиве сложно близка к O(n^2) будет только для текстов до 33 букв. А для длинных уже намного меньше.

Comment: Множества - это лучшее решение для подобной задачи, однако, согласно условиям задачи *Подсказка: используйте массив.* - видимо, сеты использовать нельзя.

Comment: Подсказка это не требование :) Скорее всего, сеты на этом уровне еще просто не проходили.

Comment: А у вас получается точно такой же проход по тексту, только перед ним еще и сортировка.

Comment: Совсем не такой проход по тексту. Поиск по массиву уникальных символов отсутствует, поскольку достаточно сравнения с предшествующим символом

Comment: точно такай же проход от начала и до конца. А поиск быстрее, чем сортировка.